# Networking code for a Golang P2P library

Tags: performance, go, networking, library

I am working in a [Noise](http://www.noiseprotocol.org/)-based P2P lib that has only basic TCP networking implemented so far. I am looking for anyone who get interested in this project that want to helps with reviews to the code and give some feedbacks about design, good practices, potential improvements, fixes, etc.

In general, it is a library that aims to serve as a tool to create secure P2P networks based on the Noise Framework.

*"[Noise](http://www.noiseprotocol.org/) is a framework for building crypto protocols. Noise protocols support mutual and optional authentication, identity hiding, forward secrecy, zero round-trip encryption, and other advanced features."*

Specifically, the code below tries to symmetrically implement the basic methods for establishing the connection between one or more peers. It uses pubsub as a pattern for internal notifications and so far a mesh [routing](https://github.com/geolffreym/p2p-noise/blob/main/network/router.go) (unstructured network).

```
package noise

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "net"
    "time"
)

// Default protocol
const PROTOCOL = "tcp"

// futureDeadline calculate a new time for deadline since now.
func futureDeadLine(deadline time.Duration) time.Time {
    return time.Now().Add(deadline * time.Second)
}

type Config interface {
    MaxPeersConnected() uint8
    MaxPayloadSize() uint32
    PeerDeadline() time.Duration
}

type Node struct {
    // Channel flag waiting for signal to close connection.
    sentinel chan bool

    // Routing hash table eg. {Socket: Conn interface}.
    router *router

    // Pubsub notifications.
    events *events

    // Configuration settings
    config Config
}

// New create a new node with default
func New(config Config) *Node {
    return &Node{
        make(chan bool),
        newRouter(),
        newEvents(),
        config,
    }
}

// Events proxy channels to subscriber.
// The listening routine should be stopped using context param.
func (n *Node) Events(ctx context.Context) <-chan Message {
    ch := make(chan Message)
    go n.events.Subscriber().Listen(ctx, ch)
    return ch // read only channel for raw messages
}

// EmitMessage emit a new message to socket.
// If socket doesn't exists or peer is not connected return error.
// Calling EmitMessage extends write deadline.
func (n *Node) EmitMessage(socket Socket, message []byte) (int, error) {
    peer := n.router.Query(socket)
    if peer == nil {
        return 0, ErrSendingMessageToInvalidPeer(socket)
    }

    bytes, err := peer.Send(message)
    // An idle timeout can be implemented by repeatedly extending
    // the deadline after successful Read or Write calls.
    // SetWriteDeadline sets the deadline for future Write calls
    // and any currently-blocked Write call.
    // Even if write times out, it may return n > 0, indicating that
    // some of the data was successfully written.
    idle := futureDeadLine(n.config.PeerDeadline())
    peer.SetWriteDeadline(idle)
    return bytes, err
}

// watch keep running waiting for incoming messages.
// After every new message the connection is verified, if local connection is closed or remote peer is disconnected the watch routine is stopped.
// Incoming message monitor is suggested to be processed in go routines.
func (n *Node) watch(peer *Peer) {

KEEPALIVE:
    for {

        // Waiting for new incoming message
        buf, err := peer.Listen(n.config.MaxPayloadSize())
        // If connection is closed
        if n.Closed() {
            // stop routines watching for peers
            return
        }

        // OverflowError is returned when the incoming payload exceed the expected size
        _, overflow := err.(OverflowError)

        // Don't stop listening for peer if overflow payload is returned.
        if err != nil && !overflow {
            // net: don't return io.EOF from zero byte reads
            // Notify about the remote peer state
            n.events.PeerDisconnected([]byte(peer.Socket()))
            // Remove peer from router table
            n.router.Remove(peer)
            return
        }

        if buf == nil {
            // `buf` is nil if no more bytes received but peer is still connected
            // Keep alive always that zero bytes are not received
            break KEEPALIVE
        }

        // Emit new incoming message notification
        n.events.NewMessage(buf)

        // An idle timeout can be implemented by repeatedly extending
        // the deadline after successful Read or Write calls.
        // SetReadDeadline sets the deadline for future Read calls
        // and any currently-blocked Read call.
        idle := futureDeadLine(n.config.PeerDeadline())
        peer.SetReadDeadline(idle)

    }

}

// routing initialize route in routing table from connection interface.
// If TCP protocol is used connection is enforced to keep alive.
// It return new peer added to table.
func (n *Node) routing(conn net.Conn) (*Peer, error) {

    // Assertion for tcp connection to keep alive
    connection, isTCP := conn.(*net.TCPConn)
    if isTCP {
        // If tcp enforce keep alive connection
        // SetKeepAlive sets whether the operating system should send keep-alive messages on the connection.
        connection.SetKeepAlive(true)
    }

    // Drop connections if max peers exceeded
    if n.router.Len() >= n.config.MaxPeersConnected() {
        log.Fatalf("max peers exceeded: MaxPeerConnected = %d", n.config.MaxPeersConnected())
        return nil, ErrExceededMaxPeers(n.config.MaxPeersConnected())
    }

    // Initial deadline for connection.
    // A deadline is an absolute time after which I/O operations
    // fail instead of blocking. The deadline applies to all future
    // and pending I/O, not just the immediately following call to
    // Read or Write. After a deadline has been exceeded, the
    // connection can be refreshed by setting a deadline in the future.
    // ref: https://pkg.go.dev/net#Conn
    idle := futureDeadLine(n.config.PeerDeadline())
    connection.SetDeadline(idle)
    // Routing connections
    remote := connection.RemoteAddr().String()
    // eg. 192.168.1.1:8080
    socket := Socket(remote)
    // We need to know how interact with peer based on socket and connection
    peer := newPeer(socket, connection)
    // Store new peer in router table
    n.router.Add(peer)
    return peer, nil
}

// Listen start listening on the given address and wait for new connection.
// Return error if error occurred while listening.
func (n *Node) Listen(addr Socket) error {

    listener, err := net.Listen(PROTOCOL, addr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Dispatch event on start listening
    n.events.Listening([]byte(addr))
    //wait until sentinel channel is closed to close listener
    defer func() {
        err := listener.Close()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(ErrClosingConnection(err).Error())
        }
    }()

    for {
        // Block/Hold while waiting for new incoming connection
        // Synchronized incoming connections
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        // If connection is closed
        if n.Closed() {
            // Graceful stop listening
            return nil
        }

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(ErrBindingConnection(err).Error())
            return err
        }

        // Routing for accepted connection
        peer, err := n.routing(conn)
        if err != nil {
            conn.Close() // Drop connection
            continue
        }

        go n.watch(peer) // Wait for incoming messages
        // Dispatch event for new peer connected
        payload := []byte(peer.Socket())
        n.events.PeerConnected(payload)
    }

}

// Table return current routing table.
func (n *Node) Table() Table {
    return n.router.Table()
}

// Closed check connection state.
// Return true for connection open else false.
func (n *Node) Closed() bool {
    select {
    // select await for sentinel if not closed then default is returned.
    case <-n.sentinel:
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}

// Close all peers connections and stop listening
func (n *Node) Close() {
    for _, peer := range n.router.Table() {
        go func(p *Peer) {
            if err := p.Close(); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(ErrClosingConnection(err).Error())
            }
        }(peer)
    }

    // Dispatch event on node get closed
    n.events.ClosedConnection()
    // If channel get closed then all routines waiting for connections
    // or waiting for incoming messages get closed too.
    close(n.sentinel)
}

// Dial attempt to connect to remote node and add connected peer to routing table.
// Return error if error occurred while dialing node.
func (n *Node) Dial(addr Socket) error {
    conn, err := net.Dial(PROTOCOL, addr)
    if err != nil {
        return ErrDialingNode(err, addr)
    }

    // Routing for dialed connection
    peer, err := n.routing(conn)
    if err != nil {
        conn.Close() // Drop connection
        return ErrDialingNode(err, addr)
    }

    go n.watch(peer) // Wait for incoming messages
    // Dispatch event for new peer connected
    n.events.PeerConnected([]byte(peer.Socket()))
    return nil
}
```

Example of usage:

**Note:** Its a work in progress so many things can change about the design or usage.

```
import (
    "context"
    "log"

    noise "github.com/geolffreym/p2p-noise"
    "github.com/geolffreym/p2p-noise/config"
)

func main() {

    // Create configurations from params and write in configurations reference
    configurations := config.New()
    configurations.Write(
        config.SetMaxPeersConnected(10),
        config.SetPeerDeadline(1800),
    )

    // Node factory
    node := noise.New(configurations)
    // Network events channel
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    var events <-chan noise.Message = node.Events(ctx)

    go func() {
        for msg := range events {
            // Here could be handled events
            if msg.Type() == noise.SelfListening {
                log.Printf("Listening on: %s \n", msg.Payload())
                cancel() // stop listening for events
            }
        }
    }()

    // ... some code here
    // node.Dial("192.168.1.1:4008")
    // node.Close()

    // ... more code here
    node.Listen("127.0.0.1:4008")

}
```

[Full code here](https://github.com/geolffreym/p2p-noise/blob/6789450bc5e876c869962cd4e1e3839c1ab90005/network/network.go)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Does the code work as expected?

Comment: Hello @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ. Yes, my tests are working and some "lab tests" in my local are working too.

Comment: Okay - thanks for confirming. It would benefit reviewers to have a bit more information about the code in the description. From [the help center page _How to ask_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): "_You will get more insightful reviews if you not only provide your code, but also give an explanation of what it does. The more detail, the better._"

Comment: I just added some extra info :) .. thank @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ